# why homepage is not reachable after adding spring security

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-security

I’m adding spring security to the web site
My goal is to show all images, home.html, and index.html to all users (without logging in).

I’ve allowed all requests for images and home and index pages, but still anonymous users cannot proceed to the home page without logging in

My security config Java

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/", "home", "index").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/styles.css", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?login_error=1")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll();
}
```

My index.html page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"       
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">

    <body>

                    <a href="login" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg">login page </a>
                    <a href="home" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg">home page</a>


    </body>
</html>
```

[image: my Image]

Comment: Can you share the complete code of that security configuration class? From what you shared it's not clear what the issue could be

Comment: I think your problem has to do with the placement of your `.anyRequest().hasRole("USER")`, but I am not positive.  Could you try placing that line before the `.antMatchers("/", "home", "index").permitAll()` line and try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried refactoring like this:
`.antMatchers("/", "home", "index").permitAll()` ->                         `.antMatchers("/", "/home", "/index").permitAll()` ?